# Initial Data Django Fixtures Issue: Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Tags: xml, django, fixtures, django-fixtures

I am having a little trouble with importing initial data through xml files.  For example I name this file in myapp/fixtures/initial_data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
  <row>
    <model>myapp.nutrition</model>
    <name>Asiago Cheese Bagel</name>
    <calories>370</calories>
    <protein >17</protein >
    <carbs>56</carbs>
    <fats>8</fats>
    <restaurant >Au Bon Pain</restaurant >
    <price>1.29</price>
  </row>
</rows>
```

And this is what my model file looks like:

```
from django.db import models
class Nutrition(models.Model):
     name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
     calories= models.IntegerField()
     protein= models.IntegerField()
     carbs= models.IntegerField()
     fats= models.IntegerField()
     restaurant= models.CharField(max_length=100)
     price= models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
```

When I run manage.py loaddata myapp/fixtures/initial_data.xml, I get:  Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s).  I have also tried JSON and got the same result.  Any ideas?

Comment: How did you created the xml file? Seems like the format is not what django understands. What django version you are trying with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should format the XML as Django expects it.  One way to go is to manually add and object using Django's admin and then dump the data using

```
manage.py dumpdata --format=xml --indent=4
```

For your case, this gives something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<django-objects version="1.0">
    <object pk="1" model="myapp.nutrition">
        <field type="CharField" name="name">Asiago Cheese Bagel</field>
        <field type="IntegerField" name="Calories">370</field>
        ...
    </object>
</django-objects>
```